# How to properly use 2 views(camera and sensors) in Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, camera

I'm a newbie to Android, but I'm trying to build an AR app that uses the back camera (using camera2) and on top of it I'm trying to show locations in that direction. At the moment I'm trying to show the location of only one place.

If I use the camera view alone, it works. If i use both views, but I don't do any computations in the Overlay view, it works as well. If I do any computations, even in an AsyncTask, I receive a CAMERA_DISCONNECTED error as soon as I launch an AsyncTask workload.

Here are the gists to my files:

ArDisplayView.java (camera): https://gist.github.com/Eteru/27af46e745287bf85942c5b6e0259126

OverlayView.java: https://gist.github.com/Eteru/27f050d7432c7e58565f43e7e7af660c

And the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 50;

    ArDisplayView arDisplay = null;
    OverlayView arContent = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Requesting camera permissions");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        FrameLayout arViewPane = findViewById(R.id.ar_view_pane);

        arDisplay = new ArDisplayView(this, this);
        arViewPane.addView(arDisplay);

        arContent = new OverlayView(this);
        arViewPane.addView(arContent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        arDisplay.openBackgroundThread();
        if (arDisplay.isAvailable()) {
            arDisplay.setupCamera(arDisplay.getWidth(), arDisplay.getHeight());
            arDisplay.openCamera();
        } else {
            arDisplay.setSurfaceTextureListener(arDisplay);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        arDisplay.closeCamera();
        arDisplay.closeBackgroundThread();

        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

In my opinion and if I understand the way AsyincTask works, the computations shouldn't affect the UI thread and this confuses me a bit.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you call:

```
Camera.Parameters params = Camera.open().getParameters();
```

Inside your `AsyncTask`, I think the `Camera` is already open, isn't it? Once you open the Camera, you can pass it to the `AsyncTask` without opening it a second time.

Comment: You are right, that was some code I found in some badly written tutorial that apparently opened the camera twice. After I changed the implementation of the camera view to camera2 I had some error that translated into "you have too many camera instances opened" which I didn't understand at the time. It works as intended now, thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Good luck with the app, it's a nice design.